# Change Zend image Captcha style

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, captcha

I have a image captcha in Zend form

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array('captcha' => array(
    'captcha'   => 'Image',
    'label'     => 'Rasmdagi belgilarni kiriting',
    'required'  => true,
    'wordLen'   => 5,
    'width'     => 150,
    'height'    => 40,
    'timeout'   => 300,
    'fontSize'  => 32,
    'gcFreq'    => 5,
    'font'      => 'files/captcha/fonts/4.ttf',
    'imgDir'    => 'files/captcha/image',
    'imgUrl'    => '/files/captcha/image',
)));
$captcha->setIgnore(true);
```

I must change it's style(background).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you cannot change the background of captcha image. It is hard coded into `Zend_Captcha_Image`. You would have to create your own captcha image class, e.g. `My_Captcha_Image` by extending `Zend_Captcha_Image` and amending the line/lines the setup background for the image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the background color is hardcoded on the core, but still you can change it!
Just search for the function **_generateImage** inside the core files and change how the background is created

Ex.:
To change the background color change the lines:

> $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

And

> $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($img2, 255, 255, 255);